# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sumOfOdd' referenced before assignment in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cs50

I'm trying to run this code:

```
number = input("Number: ")
valid = False
sumOfOdd = 0

def validation(credit_num):
    for i in range(len(credit_num)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sumOfOdd += i


def main():
    print(f"Your credit card number is {number}, it's third digit is {number[2]}")
    print(f'sum of odds: {sumOfOdd}')

validation(number)
main()
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "credit.py", line 15, in <module>
    validation(number)
  File "credit.py", line 8, in validation
    sumOfOdd += i
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sumOfOdd' referenced before assignment
```

I'm able to run, but when I input any number it gives me this error

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the variable `sumOfOdd` is not accessible from within the function. You could declare the [variable `global` in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function), but you should be careful using the `global` statement.

In my opinion, a better way to do this is to supply `sumOfOdd` as an argument to the function and return the updated variable:

```
def validation(credit_num, sumOfOdd):
    for i in range(len(credit_num)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sumOfOdd += i
    return sumOfOdd

validation(number, 0)
# Returns the correct sum.
```

Or, if you know that the `sumOfOdd` should always be initialized by zero, you could define the variable locally:

```
def validation(credit_num):
    sumOfOdd = 0
    for i in range(len(credit_num)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sumOfOdd += i
    return sumOfOdd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your code.

Note that it now iterates through `credit_num` as `for num in credit_num`. If you use `for i in range(len(credit_num))` you are iterating through a list of indexes and would need to use `if int(credit_num[i]) % 2 != 0`, reason being that `range(N)` returns a list `[0, 1, 2... N-1]` where `for num in credit_num` iterates through `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]` if your input string was `1111222233334444`

```
number = input("Number: ")
valid = False
sumOfOdd = 0

def validation(credit_num):
    global sumOfOdd
    for num in credit_num:
        if int(num) % 2 != 0:
            sumOfOdd += 1


def main():
    print(f"Your credit card number is {number}, it's third digit is {number[2]}")
    print(f'sum of odds: {sumOfOdd}')

validation(number)
main()
```

Note that `validation(number)` is called in global scope along with `main()`, hence the `global sumOfOdd` declaration inside to allow `def validation` to gain access to that variable.

A different way to write this code to make it more readable would be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = input("Number: ")
    valid = False
    sumOfOdd = 0
    
    def validation(credit_num):
        sumOfOddToReturn = 0
        for num in credit_num:
            if int(num) % 2 != 0:
                sumOfOddToReturn += 1
        return sumOfOddToReturn
    
    sumOfOdd = validation(number)
    
    print(f"Your credit card number is `{number}`, its third digit is `{number[2]}`.")
    print(f'sum of odds: {sumOfOdd}')
```